# how to add column with a legend in doughnut chart

Tags: html, donut-chart

Hi I have taken a reference of doughnut chart from google api and all working fine.

But i have two queries:

a. How to add one more column for the values with the legend as shown in image

[image]

b. When focus on specific field how the increase the size of image as shown in image.

[image]

here is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Total Expenses in percentage'],
          ['Home Loan', 28],
          ['Rent', 23],
          ['Other EMI',  11],
          ['Utilities', 7],
          ['Childrens Education', 6],
          ['Recreation', 25]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Total Annual Expenses',
          colors:['#CCCCCC','#D95B43','#C02942','#542437','#53777A','#ECD078'],
          pieHole: 0.5,
          pieSliceText: 'Annual Expenses',

          pieSliceTextStyle: {color: 'Annual Expenses', fontName: 'Century Gothic', fontSize: 14}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
    <div id="donutchart" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="pieholetext" style="position:relative; width: 50px; height: 30px; margin-top: 20px;  bottom:235px;
       left:230px;">Annual Expenses</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a reference link is [reference](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Overview)

Please suggest how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example of code and a link to the relevant API. Also, please tag this with whatever that chart is generated with, because it is NOT pure HTML.

Comment: I have edit the code please check

Comment: Can't you just add a new one to the list  `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`, and then add the desired color to `colors`?